# Creates more items on instantiateItem and not only one as default

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragmentstatepageradapter, android-pageradapter

I have an adapter (`FragmentStatePagerAdapter`) with arrows, that each click creates the next page:

```
    leftArrow.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
        }
    });
    rightArrow.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1);

        }
    });

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {
    int i=0;
    for (i=position; i<position+2;i++){
    MyPage currentPage = pages.get(i);
    if(page == null){
        currentPage = new MyPage(i);
        pages.put(i, page);     
        super.instantiateItem(collection, i);
    }
    }

    return super.instantiateItem(collection, position);
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    MyPage pageToRemove = pages.get(position);
    if(pageToRemove != null){
        pageToRemove.dispose();
        pages.remove(position);
    }
    super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
}
}
```

I want to create on each iteration not 1 page but 3, because I have delays while paging. I tried to create the pages and insert them into array but the problem is that I have only ONE return that return `return super.instantiateItem(collection, position);`

Any ideas how can I call it few more times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any ideas how can I call it few more times?

You're not the one doing the calling -- `ViewPager` is. You can call [`setOffscreenPageLimit()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit%28int%29) to increase the number of pages that `ViewPager` will cache. By default, the value is 1, meaning that `ViewPager` will cache 3 pages (the current one, plus one to either side). Bumping that to 2 will have `ViewPager` cache 5 pages, and so on.

Bear in mind:

- This slows down setting up the `ViewPager`, and so it is not really a solution for slow pages
- This consumes more heap space